# How to change my code for methods in the APIView to be called in the right order?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am implementing an API for a game using DRF view (more specifically APIViews). I have figured out how to use more than one serializer for a view but I need this view to combine multiple models and think that I need more than one GET as well as more than one POST method. Is this even possible? My code so far looks like this:

```
class GameView(APIView):
    """
    API View that retrieves the game,
    retrieves an empty game session to be filled with the necessary data and sent back to the server
    retrieves a random resource per round
    allows users to post tags that are verified and saved accordingly to either the Label or VerifiedLabel table
    """
    renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer, HTMLFormRenderer)
    controller = GameViewController()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        YOUR_DEFAULT_SERIALIZER = GametypeSerializer
        YOUR_SERIALIZER_1 = GamesessionSerializer
        YOUR_SERIALIZER_2 = GameroundSerializer
        YOUR_SERIALIZER_3 = ResourceSerializer
        YOUR_SERIALIZER_4 = VerifiedLabelSerializer
        YOUR_SERIALIZER_5 = LabelSerializer

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return YOUR_SERIALIZER_4 and YOUR_SERIALIZER_5 and YOUR_SERIALIZER_1
        elif self.request.method == 'GET':
            return YOUR_SERIALIZER_2 and YOUR_SERIALIZER_3
        else:
            return YOUR_DEFAULT_SERIALIZER

    def get_queryset(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        obj = None
        resources = None
        chosen_gametype = None
        gameround = None
        gamesession = None

        while obj is None:
            if obj == resources:
                while resources is None:
                    random_idx = random.randint(0, Resource.objects.count() - 1)
                    resources = Resource.objects.all().filter(id=random_idx)
                    obj = resources

            elif obj == chosen_gametype:
                while chosen_gametype is None:
                    chosen_gametype = Gametype.objects.all().filter(name="imageLabeler")
                    obj = chosen_gametype

            elif obj == gamesession:
                while gamesession is None:
                    # TODO: figure out how to send empty gamesession
                    gamesession = Gamesession.objects.none()
                    obj = gamesession

            elif obj == gameround:
                while gameround is None:
                    # TODO: figure out how to send empty gameround
                    gameround = Gameround.objects.none()
                    obj = gameround

        return obj

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """

        :param request:
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        model = request.GET.get("model")
        serializer = None
        # TODO: find way to assign what model is?
        model = "Gametype"  # For testing purposes only!
        while serializer is None:

            if model == "Gametype":
                gametype = self.get_queryset()
                serializer = GametypeSerializer(gametype, many=True)
                resource = self.get_queryset()
                serializer = ResourceSerializer(resource, many=True)

            elif model == "Gameround":
                gameround = Gameround.objects.none()
                serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround, many=True)

            elif model == "Gamesession":
                gamesession = Gamesession.objects.none()
                serializer = GamesessionSerializer(gamesession, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """

        :param request:
        :param args:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        saved_gameround = None
        saved_gamesession = None
        saved_label = None
        saved_verified_label = None
        saved_obj = None

        model = request.GET.get("model")
        model = "Label"

        if model == "Gameround":
            gameround = GameroundSerializer(data=request.data)
            while saved_gameround is None:
                serializer = GameroundSerializer(data=gameround)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    saved_gameround = serializer.save()
                    saved_obj = saved_gameround
                    return Response(saved_obj, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        elif model == "Gamesession":
            gamesession = request.data.get_queryset()
            while saved_gamesession is None:
                serializer = GamesessionSerializer(data=gamesession)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    saved_gamesession = serializer.save()
                    saved_obj = saved_gamesession
                    return Response(saved_obj, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        elif model == "Label":
            # test & modify if necessary
            label = serializer.ResourceWithTaggingsSerializer(data=request.data)
            while saved_label is None:
                serializer = ResourceWithTaggingsSerializer(data=tagging)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    saved_label = serializer.save()
                    saved_obj = saved_label
                    return Response(saved_obj, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        elif model == "VerifiedLabel":
            # TODO: add condition to only save to tag if condition met
            # tag = request.data.get_queryset()
            verified_label = serializer.ResourceWithTagsSerializer(data=request.data)
            while saved_verified_label is None:
                serializer = ResourceWithTagsSerializer(data=verified_label)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    saved_verified_label = serializer.save()
                    saved_obj = saved_verified_label
                    return Response(saved_obj, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(saved_obj, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I think it is worth mentioning that I plan on using a single url for this. It should work like this: a user clicks a game type and then this view is called and the game starts and everything is handled that needs to be handled during the game.
*I have set model = "Model" to test. I am looking for a way to do this differently.

Comment: What do you mean multiple GET or POST? A single url like /api/example could have different behavior based on the body or data params of the http request?

Comment: It is possible but it seems like a bad practice. If you really want to use single url i suggest using protobuf.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use just one url you can get it done with GET parameters.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    model = request.GET.get("model")
    if model == "Gametype":
        .. do something with the Gametype model ..
    elif model == "Resource":
        .. do something with the Resource model ..
```

same for `get_serializer_class()` so you know which serializer to use.

Then you would call `/gameview/?model=Gametype` or `/gameview/?model=Resource`

But what's so wrong about using multiple urls in the first place?

Comment: As far as I know one view can only be connected to one url and I have to have one view for the game (since it's a simple picture labelling game).

Comment: can I use the same approach for the post method as well?

Comment: Yes, GET parameters also work for POST requests.

Comment: I meant can I do something like this model = request.POST.post("model") for the post method?

Comment: No, you still have to do `request.GET.get()`

Comment: I updated my code - did I understand you correctly?